# Keeping aspect ratio of a control

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I've looked for quite a while now for a way to be able to tell a WPF control (or window) to keep a certain aspect ratio.

1. For a `Window` I found [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b0df3d1f-e211-4f54-a079-09af0096410e/keeping-a-windows-aspect-ratio-during-resize?forum=wpf) solution, that works quite well. But since it uses the Win32 API and window handles it's not working for any WPF `Control`s (because as far as I know in WPF only the window itself has a handle)
2. For a `Control` one usually gets the advice to put the `Control` in a `ViewBox`, but I don't want to scale my controls, I want them to resize (and keep any border width or font size).
3. Other "solutions" for a `Control` involve any form of binding the `Width` to the `ActualHeight` or the `Height` to the `ActualWidth`, or using the `SizeChanged` event, but this results in heavy flickering while resizing and it's not very reliable.
   In case of binding the `Width` to the `ActualHeight` you can't resize only the `Width` (by dragging the right border) because the `ActualHeight` doesn't change.
   In case of the event it gets tricky when width and height change at the same time, then you'd have to change the size inside the `SizeChanged` event... and did I mention the flickering?

After a lot of reading and searching I came to the conclusion that the best way to force any control to keep a certain aspect ratio would be to do that inside the `Measure` and `Arrange` functions.

I found [this](https://coding4life.wordpress.com/2012/10/15/wpf-resize-maintain-aspect-ratio/) solution that creates a `Decorator` control with overridden `Measure` and `Measure` functions, but that would mean to put any control that's supposed to keep it's aspect ratio inside it's own `Decorator`. I could live with that if I had to, but I wonder if there's a better way to do it.

So, here's my question. Is it possible to create an attached property `Ratio` and an attached property `KeepRatio` and somehow override the `Measure` and `Arrange` functions of the controls in question in the `OnKeepRatioChanged` and `RatioChanged` callbacks of the attached properties?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to override Arrange/Measure methods then there is no need in attached properties. This wrapper should be fine:

```
public partial class RatioKeeper : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty VerticalAspectProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "VerticalAspect", typeof(double), typeof(RatioKeeper), new PropertyMetadata(1d));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HorizontalAspectProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "HorizontalAspect", typeof(double), typeof(RatioKeeper), new PropertyMetadata(1d));

    public double HorizontalAspect
    {
        get { return (double) GetValue(HorizontalAspectProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HorizontalAspectProperty, value); }
    }

    public double VerticalAspect
    {
        get { return (double) GetValue(VerticalAspectProperty); }
        set { SetValue(VerticalAspectProperty, value); }
    }
    public RatioKeeper()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //arrangeBounds provides size of a host.
    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeBounds)
    {
        //Calculation of a content size that wont exceed host's size and will be of the desired ratio at the same time
        var horizontalPart = arrangeBounds.Width / HorizontalAspect;
        var verticalPart = arrangeBounds.Height / VerticalAspect;
        var minPart = Math.Min(horizontalPart, verticalPart);
        var size = new Size(minPart * HorizontalAspect, minPart * VerticalAspect);
        //apply size to wrapped content
        base.ArrangeOverride(size);
        //return size to host
        return size;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd very much like to do it in an attached behavior so that I can use it on a button or a Grid or a ListView or a Window.